# Is it OK to modify the `intrinsicContentSize` method for `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I want to use `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` with autolayout. However since they don't have the `intrinsicContentSize` method, it is hard to set constraint for all the views.

Is it OK if I modify the `intrinsicContentSize` method of them to return the `contentSize` for `UITableView` and `self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize` for `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `intrinsicContentSize` the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize) states that:

> Overriding this method allows a custom view to communicate to the
>   layout system what size it would like to be based on its content.

As `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are both subclasses of the `UIView`, this method must work for them too. I don't see any cautions in the docs about using it with them.

You can also check out this great [tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/) concerning Auto Layout, and Intrinsic Content Size in particular. Pay attention to the following:

> To implement an intrinsic content size in a custom view, you have to
>   do two things: override intrinsicContentSize to return the appropriate
>   size for the content, and call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize whenever
>   something changes which affects the intrinsic content size.

So don't forget to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` when your table view reloads data, inserts new rows etc. And the same applies to the `UICollectionView`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder if it is acceptable why UIKIT didn't do it as default.

Comment: Idk, maybe this is because they don't wanna add the overhead of generation the private constraints for `intrinsicContentSize` behind the scenes without explicit user request (by subclassing `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`).